# ¿Error de sintaxis en definición de función?

Tags: python, sintaxis

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio del libro "Aprende a pensar como un programador en Python", el cual se basa en crear una clase "Hora", e introducir distintos métodos. El problema es que cuando ejecuto el código el intérprete me marca un error de sintaxis.

```
class Hora:
    def __init__(self, hora = 0 , minutos = 0 , segundos = 0):
        self.hora = hora
        self.minutos = minuto
        self.segundos = segundos

    def incremento(self, segundos):
        self.segundos += segundos
        while self.segundos >= 60 or self.minutos >= 60:
            if self.segundos >= 60:
                self.segundos -= 60
                self.minutos += 1
            elif self.minutos >= 60:
                self.minutos -= 60
                self.horas += 1
        return self.horas, self.minutos, self.segundos

    def imprimeHora(self):
        print (str(self.horas) + ":" + str(self.minutos= + ":" + str(self.segundos))

    def convierteASegundos(self):
        minutos = self.horas * 60 + self.minutos
        segundos = minutos * 60 + self.segundos
        return segundos

    def despues(self, t2):
        if self.horas > t2.horas and self.minutos > t2.minutos and self.segundos > t2.segundos:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
```

Cuando intento ejecutarlo tengo la siguiente salida:

```
  File "hora.py", line 21
def convierteASegundos(self):
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer para poder lograr que el programa se ejecute correctamente?

Comment: verifica el espacio o tabs, debes tener algo mal alli

Comment: Acabo de checkear, y nada diferente.

Comment: te falta unos parentesis en la linea del return de `imprimeHora` y tienes un `=` donde no debe acomoda la linea a `print (str(self.horas) + ":" + str(self.minutos + ":" + str(self.segundos)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el print de la funcion `imprimeHora` tienes un `=` en vez de un `)`

Tendria que quedar asi:

```
print (str(self.horas) + ":" + str(self.minutos) + ":" + str(self.segundos))
```

Comment: Para estos casos en los que son un error tipografico, no se debe contestar, si no marcar el error en un comentario y la pregunta se cierra por ese motivo. Esta clase de errores no ayuda a otras personas y suelen generar ruido en el sitio.

Comment: Lo siento, no tenia los puntos necesarios para poner un comentario, y cuando respondí aun no había respuesta

Comment: Igual se agradece la intencion. Estaba en un comentario lo que marcaste.